# Is there a way to create a popup modal without an CMS, that is editable by specific users?

Tags: javascript, html, web, modal-dialog, popup

I am looking for a feature, that would allow a user to login to the site and edit the HTML text + save it.

By researching it everyone points to a CRM. However, is it possible to add a feature like that, and what would be needed to do so? Is this even possible without a CMS?

Comment: You'd need some kind of permission system (who is allowed to edit the modal) and then a way to receive and store what the user wrote and then a way to display that data on the modal.  The permission system might be the most challenging part, something that could typically be handled by a CMS, but with enough coding savvy there's no reason you couldn't make your own.

Comment: Thank you for getting back James. I see what you are saying, so basically it would be possible, but for a beginner maybe too much (like myself).